# LTE system simulator

Tags: lte

I want LTE-sim Simulator. I could not find it.
it is related to this paper
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5634134/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here is the LTE-Sim Simulator you are looking for "https://github.com/lte-sim/lte-sim-dev"